# how to read partition keys from existing hive table

Tags: linux, shell, hive, hiveql

I am trying to read data from source hive table to target hive table, part of this I create 
    table in target hive database using source database table schema and I have no issues doing
    so however I would like to read partition keys dynamically and insert them in load statement 
    so that data imported to target table.

I am wondering if anyone could help me to read partition keys from existing table schema?

here is sample table schema...

```
     hive> describe extended pageviews;
     OK
     eventtime               string
     userid                  string
     page                    string
     dt                      string
     applicationtype         string

# Partition Information
# col_name              data_type               comment

dt                      string
applicationtype         string

Detailed Table Information      
Table(tableName:pageviews, dbName:default, owner:root, createTime:1413687270, lastAccessTime:0, retention:0, 
sd:StorageDescriptor(cols:[FieldSchema(name:eventtime, type:string, comment:null), 
FieldSchema(name:userid, type:string, comment:null), 
FieldSchema(name:page, type:string, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:dt, type:string,  comment:null),
FieldSchema(name:applicationtype, type:string, comment:null)], location:hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/apps/hive/warehouse/pageviews,
 inputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat, outputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat, 
compressed:false, numBuckets:-1, serdeInfo:SerDeInfo(name:null, 
serializationLib:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, 
parameters:{serialization.format=1}), bucketCols:[], sortCols:[], parameters:{}, 
  skewedInfo:SkewedInfo(skewedColNames:[], skewedColValues:[], skewedColValueLocationMaps:{}),
  storedAsSubDirectories:false), partitionKeys:[FieldSchema(name:dt, type:string, comment:null),  
FieldSchema(name:applicationtype, type:string, comment:null)],
 parameters:{transient_lastDdlTime=1413687270}, viewOriginalText:null,
   viewExpandedText:null, tableType:MANAGED_TABLE)

Time taken: 0.903 seconds, Fetched: 13 row(s)
```

Comment: people will vote to close this. You need to add your expected output from this input, and preferably some code that shows you attempted to solve your problem. Would also be good to include tag for your OS, as windows shell solution would be much different that a *nix solution. Good luck.

Comment: sorry. I tried formatting it and had a problem of saving my changes as I was keep seeing add more meaningful comments your code message which eventually not allowed me to save formatted text.

Comment: there is probably a timer on editting your question now. Try back in 1, 4, 8, 24 hrs. It is probably seeing that you only did spaces? So focus on adding your required output. Good luck.

Comment: why can't you read partitions simply as 'select distinct dt from pageviews where <>' ?